# How to send data to servlet using ajax with a submit button

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I am new with servlet, I want to get the data in the servlet using ajax and jquery. it execute but i did not get data in servlet
on the click of the submit button the only error part is execute of ajax
my index page is

```
 I am new with servlet, I want to get the data in the servlet using ajax and jquery. it execute but i did not get data in servlet
```

on the click of the submit button the only error part is execute of ajax
my index page is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First jQuery Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align=center>
            <form id="myform">
                <pre>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" name='name' id='name' />
                    Email:
                    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
                    Address:
                    <input type='text' name='address' id='address'>
                        <input type='submit' value='submit' id='mysubmit'>
                </pre>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("Onready the page");
                $("#myform").on('submit',(function(e){
                    alert("button clicked");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var name=$("#name").val();
                    var address=$("#address").val();
                    var email=$("#email").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "reg",
                        type: "GET",
                        data:{name:name,email:email,address:address},
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData:false,
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                }));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

---

Comment: Your post isn't complete

Answer (score 3):

1 ) import latest jquery file 
2 )

```
<script>$(".your form class").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "Servlet Path",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }           
        })
    }));</script/>
```

Comment: Ok I realized this is what was needed and this is correct. Just one point. If you want the request to be asynchronous (which is the whole purpose of ajax in case), mention async: true in the request body. That will serve the purpose.

Comment: Also, I dont think you can have spaces between class-name-text in $(".your form class") .

Comment: i just put it for your knowledge so you can remove it and replace with your class

Comment: importing latest jquery solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ajax to send data to your servlet. You need to define a route to your servlet in web.xml, and mention a submit action for your form. For example,

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloForm</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloForm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This is the entry for your application's web.xml file and

```
<form action="HelloForm" method="GET">
```

This needs to be your form tag for an example servlet with class name 'HelloForm'. Clicking the submit button of this form will send your form field data to your servlet. Take care of the 'name' of the form fields. To access a field named 'field 1' (Example Ninput name="field1">), the code in your servlet needs to be request.getParameter("field1").

Hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: I agree with you but OP WANTS to use AJAX

Comment: Ok, I realized why you would need AJAX. Pratik's answer would serve your purpose. Added a comment below his answer.